# Appengine app does not request login in production mode

Tags: google-app-engine, authentication

My appengine app normally requests a login in development (or debug) mode.  However, in production mode it is not requesting an login.  I have the "Authentication Options" set to "Google Accounts API" in the appengine Application Settings tab.

This is my first appengine app deployed to the appengine server.  Am I missing a setting somewhere?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to test login functionality, make sure that you are logged out of any Google accounts that you use. Otherwise, It'll probably pick up that authorization and skip the login screen.

Comment: Thanks Adam.  Yes, I have made sure I'm logged out of any Google account.  I even opened up a new browser and cleared the cache and confirmed on a Google account page that I'm not logged in.  I also tried it from an "incognito" Chrome window, same problem.  Any other ideas?

Comment: How are you requiring log in on page-by-page basis? Is it in your `app.yaml`?

Comment: I haven't touched the default app.yaml that gets built in Eclipse using GPE. But dev mode does always require me to login, and I only have one page.  Pardon the newbie question, but what should I have in my app.yaml for this?  (I'm researching this file now).  Thanks.

Comment: You can find out about app.yaml files here: http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/appconfig.html#Requiring_Login_or_Administrator_Status

Comment: There is a specific way to indicate that your application wants to require logins. If the problem isn't that you are already logged in, it is difficult to impossible to say what the issue might be without seeing your application's `app.yaml` and request-handling source code. You consider adding them to your question.

Comment: Thanks Adam. It turns out that my app doesn't use app.yaml, but instead uses web.xml and appengine-web.xml.  When I fixed those files, the login was required. If you add your comments about app.yaml (and/or web.xml) to the answer I can accept ti.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add "login: required" on all the appropriate handlers in your app.yaml.